# how to fill C# Fill rectangle From bottom to top?

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I have drawn vertical Rectangle but i want to fill it from bottom to top.
here is the code i used

```
System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush linGrBrush = 
    new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(
           new Point(0, 12),
           new Point(0,2),
           Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0),
           Color.FromArgb(255, 190, 0, 0));

Pen pen = new Pen(linGrBrush);

e.Graphics.FillRectangle(linGrBrush,groupBox2.Width -50,10, 25,  x);

using (Pen Pen1 = new Pen(Color.BurlyWood, 4))
{
   e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pen1, groupBox2.Width -50,10, 25, 200);
}
```

x is color fill offset which fill is used to fill rectangle after every 2 seconds.

Comment: Try reducing the y coordinate while increasing the height. Start from the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should adjust the starting and the ending points of the gradient:

```
System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush linGrBrush = 
         new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(
               new Point(0, 1),
               new Point(0,0),
               Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0),
               Color.FromArgb(255, 190, 0, 0));
```

Comment: i Tried but its not starting point of rectangle it just change pattern of fill . i have to change top of rectangle but i dont know how to :(